# Alternative to Microsoft.TeamFoundation.* and TfsTeamProjectCollection

Tags: c#, tfs, visual-studio-2013, tfs-sdk

I'm simply looking for some sort of alternative to the Microsoft teamfoundation dlls.  We are using visual studio 2013 do develop our software, and our updater software pulls information from TFS.

Most people using the software do not require Visual Studio and are using Visual Studio Team Explorer 2008 instead (licenses are cheaper than a full visual studio license).

The issue arises when the people using team explorer try to update, but have an older version of Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.  Team Explorer 2008 uses Microsoft.TeamFoundation 9.0 where Visual studio 2013 uses version 12.0.

We have tried bundling the 12.0 dll with the updater, but the chain of dependencies after that just keeps going, and will need to constantly bundle/update those dlls.

If anyone has any ideas for an alternative, it would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Edit:  I realize I didn't mention the two dll's reall in question here.  The two in use are:

```
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client;
```

And there are only 3 lines of code even using these.  These three lines are what I'm currently (and unsuccessfully) trying to find an alternative for:

```
TfsTeamProjectCollection projects = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("some uri"));
VersionControlServer vsStore = projects.GetService<VersionControlServer>();

ItemSet items = vsStore.GetItems(sourcePath, VersionSpec.Latest, RecursionType.OneLevel);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to install Visual Studio 2013, you could only install [Team Explorer 2013](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40776). Or you could install Visual Studio Community version. This version is free.

I suggest that you could install a Nuget package[(TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient/14.102.0)) for your project. Then you don't need to install VS or Team Explorer on other machines. All client assemblies about TFS are added to your project after installing this package. Install this package is also free. The assemblies in this package are 14.0, and it is compatible with TFS 2013 and you could use the same with 12.0.

Comment: GiulioVian and @Tingting0929-MSFT are right. From a programming perspective, you said just using the `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client` and `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client`, but actually these two libraries will refer to other dependent tfs APIs. You can do a test, copy these two libraries into your project and add reference to them directly. Then you will find that your code thrown exception "cannot load library `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common`",it's because you have not add reference to this DLL, so it will automatically add reference to the default location.(c:\..)

Comment: That's why you need to install Team Explorer 2013, it will install the entire DLLs in the default location. Once your program cannot load some tfs libs, it will automatically load them from the default location.

Comment: Thank you guys for the response, it's greatly appreciated.  Unfortunately upgrading Team Explorer isn't really an option at the moment.  I'll refer you to the comment I left on Guilio Vian for more details.  I appreciate the responses!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Why not upgrading users to Team Explorer 2013, the same you use?

It has no additional licensing (you need a CAL even if you use a browser, and you must have a call for 2008, don't you?) and can be installed side-by-side.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I had a feeling this was the only solution.  Unfortunately at my work place, get software approved and onto everyones machine is a LONG process.  We're talking years (I'm not sure why), but that's what I've been told when bringing this solution to managers.  Why Team Explorer wasn't upgraded when Visual studio I also don't know.  Anyway, I appreciate the response!  Thank you!